# webview is always null

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have a `WebViewFragment` and when trying to get the webview to use, it gives me a null pointer

```
public class BallInfoFragment extends WebViewFragment {
long id;

public BallInfoFragment(long id){
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state){
    super.onCreate(state);
    String ball = new String();
    Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Balls.CONTENT_URI,new String[] {Balls.ID,Balls.BALL},Balls.ID+"="+id,null,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    ball = c.getString(1);
    WebView wv = getWebView();  //getWebView always gives me null
```

why is it null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the code within the `onActivityCreated()` function instead. This is called after the `WebView` has been instantiated.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  // your code here.
  WebView wv = getWebView();
}
```

`onCreate` is called when the activity is created, before the `WebView` has been.

Comment: that did it, but it wont display anything now. it tells me that it cant find the html file I have in my assets folder and i declare like this `wv.loadUrl("file///android_asset/train.html");` file name is correct

Answer (score 2):

Jivings is correct, but to clarify most of the time you'll want to retrieve and attach your views in the `onCreateView` method, which is where inflation of the parent view hierarchy occurs. The default implementation of `onCreateView` in `WebViewFragment` attaches the `WebView` to the parent view for you, so you don't need to worry about it in this case (the same is true with similar classes such as `ListFragment`). I thought it was worth mentioning. If you simply want to retrieve your view from the `Activity`'s view layout, you should do this in `onActivityCreated`, as at this is called only after the `Activity`'s layout has been created. In the code above, you are retrieving the view before it has been attached, and `getWebView` is correctly returning null.

Make sure you understand the `Fragment` lifecycle, it's really important!

Comment: ok so maybe you can answer this then, why wont it display my html file in my assets folder? and I declare like this in my `onActivityCreated` `wv.loadUrl("file///android_asset/train.html");` file name is correct

Comment: do you mean `wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/train.html");`? with a colon before the back slashes?